# Programatically Zoom into section of chart where a marker is being displayed

Tags: swift, macos, ios-charts

In a Mac app I am trying to zoom into a section on **x** axis where a Marker is currently visible.

I am using some logic as per below to figure out the x position:

```
private func getZoomXPosition() -> CGFloat {
    var x = 0.0
    if let highlight = self.chartView.highlighted.first {
        print("highlight x=\(highlight.x) drawX=\(highlight.drawX)")
        let pos = chartView.getMarkerPosition(highlight: highlight)
        x = pos.x
    }
    print("zoom to x: \(x)")
    return x
}
```

If a highlight exists (then we have a marker showing at that position)

I am then calling:

```
self.chartView.zoom(scaleX: 1.5, scaleY: 1.0, x: x, y: 0)
```

To perform the zoom to that x position. This appears to work mostly except once you get to a certain zoom level the next zoom in appears to zoom to the wrong point.

```
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=286.3808824269045
zoom to x: 286.3808824269045
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=272.58693711440446
zoom to x: 272.58693711440446
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=262.2414781300295
zoom to x: 262.2414781300295
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=258.36193101088895
zoom to x: 258.36193101088895
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=259.0893460957275
zoom to x: 259.0893460957275
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=258.3391992894881
zoom to x: 258.3391992894881
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=260.06219273506895
zoom to x: 260.06219273506895
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=252.83369679540647
zoom to x: 252.83369679540647
clicked ChartDataEntry, x: 3125.0, y 393.0
highlight x=3125.0 drawX=303.74376780794955
zoom to x: 303.74376780794955
```

as you can see by the logs the 9th zoom in always causes the issue.

Update 18 march:

I've updated method above to include the prints.

So I'm finding the current highlighted position on the chart

`chartView.hightlighted.first`

then I am converting this to the actual point on the chart

`chartView.getMarkerPosition(highlight: highlight`

and then finally calling

`cahrtView.zoom()`

with that x and an x scale factor of 1.5.

It works fine up until the 8th level zooming in (by clicking a zoom in button). the 9th one always zooms into the wrong part of the chart.

Comment: I'm working with Charts in MacOS as well, so I'd love to help, but I can't make sense of your output here. Could you add code to your question that shows what is calling those `print` statements? Also, what output are you expecting in the 9th zoom?

Comment: updated to try and make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks for adding detail. I'm still not sure what your expected output is in the print statements-- it looks like every instance logged shows `drawX` and `zoom to x` are equal, and I don't see how that changes on the 8th or 9th run. Is the project in git somewhere where I could take a look and try running it to see for myself?

Comment: I made a short video showing the issue https://youtu.be/XCc5RHiuujA . I could try to get a test app going.

Comment: I see now. That is weird. I don't know what's causing that, but I'll write up an answer in a little bit that has the code I use to zoom in on a given point, which might work better. Hopefully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of `zoom` functions in `ChartViewBase`, and I've had trouble wrapping my head around all of them, so I've only been using one particular one and writing helper functions to call it the way I prefer. Hopefully this will work correctly for you:

```
func zoomToPosition(
    _ position: CGPoint,
    xMultiplier: Double,
    yMultiplier: Double,
    axis: YAxis.AxisDependency
) {
    // position is a pixel location.
    // valuePosition is the corresponding value in the chart for the pixel
    let valuePosition = chartView.valueForTouchPoint(point: position, axis: axis)
    
    // the version of `zoom` that we'll call seems to work best with
    // x and y scales calculated manually rather than using the built-in
    let newXScale = chartView.viewPortHandler.scaleX * xMultiplier
    let newYScale = chartView.viewPortHandler.scaleY * yMultiplier
    
    chartView.zoom(scaleX: newXScale, scaleY: newYScale, xValue: valuePosition.x, yValue: valuePosition.y, axis: axis)
}
```

I just tried using this code to zoom in on my existing project, and it works well beyond ten iterations.

Here's how I can see it being used in your case:

```
let xPos = getZoomXPosition()
let zoomPos = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: 0.0)
zoomToPosition(zoomPos, xMultiplier: 1.4, yMultiplier: 1.0, axis: .left)
```

Fingers crossed that this will work :-)

Comment: Yes this seems to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful! Glad we didn't need to figure out exactly what was going wrong with the original code :-)